# NY short stories - woman wears towel for landlord, woman tricks rich man to take her to Napa, priest falls into elevator shaft while wrestling a drunk

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

A woman who won't pay the rent.  When the landlord comes to the door and tries to talk to her, she stands with only a very short towel in front of her.  Eventually she has to move and does this all over again.

A woman who goes to SF once a year to a bar and tricks a wealthy man into taking her to the Napa Wine Country (and does not sleep with him).

Priest who tends to drunks in the Bowery.  He wrestles a drunk man in an abandoned building to help him, and falls down an elevator shaft.

There are about three more stories I can't remember. What is this book of short stories about people in New York City (1970s, fiction)?